# URL writing using $_SERVER parms

Tags: php, html

So I have a bunch of URLs that I need to write, Is it bad practice to begin the urls with:

```
$_SERVER['http_host']
```

so my URL would look like this:

```
echo"<a href='http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$category."/".$article."'>link</a>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be uppercase `HTTP_HOST`. And while this is a client-supplied value, on most shared hosting servers this field is pre-filtered by Apache. So it's safe to use this way (apply `htmlspecialchars` anyway).

You forgot the `http://` protocol prefix however for your link.

If you need it for a "bunch of urls" it would make sense to package it into a separate function. Commonly this also handles the optional `HTTP_PORT` being anything but the standard `80`.

Answer (score 1):

Terrible practice. It won't even work.

1. It is `HTTP_HOST` not `http_host`
2. You are missing the protocol

Even if it did, you'd end up with code that was much easier to read if you simply used relative URIs and interpolation:

```
echo "<a href='/$category/$article'>link</a>";
```

Comment: The code was just an example it wasn't an exact copy paste from what I was planning on using. Relative paths won't work given that they are being used on a bar that is globally displayed on the site.

Comment: They will if you start them with a `/`.

Comment: No I am saying It is in the header I have no way of knowing where the person is on the board. I am not going to code a separate navbar for every possible page that the member can be on that is even worse practice.

Comment: *sigh*. If the path **starts** with a `/` then it is relative to the *root* of the site, not the current path. So you **don't** need to adjust based on where on the site you are. (Unless the site is split across multiple hostnames, but dumping anything in `$_SERVER` into the URI wouldn't help with that either).